# "Return" in the middle of a script

Tags: python, debugging, return, exit

I'm debugging a script and temporarily would like to stop the script in the middle and plot some of the values for different variables.  Is there no way in Python to "return" from a script?  I don't want to exit Python entirely.  What I want, in essence, is to freeze the script at a particular point.  It would be so nice if there were a single command I could insert -- e.g., `return` -- that would do this -- which I would then remove when finished with the debugging.

Here are a couple of ways to achieve this sort of thing that I consider inelegant in the context of my work at this moment:

(1) Put the script's code in a function, and return the needed variables midway through this function.

(2) Comment out all the code after the point at which I want to stop.

(3) Save all the desired variables to disk, and use a call to `quit` or `sys.exit` to exit Python entirely.

Is there no better option?

### Theoretical question

Why would the designers of Python have decided not to allow `return` statements in scripts?  Is there a logic to that?

Comment: @dbliss have you *tried* using `matplotlib` within pdb?

Comment: @dbliss I just tried it with this: https://gist.github.com/waynew/0b259f8280f317226428a35fa07ce1ce and even running the `plt.plot(data); plt.show()` from within pdb works just fine. So... what doesn't work for you?

Comment: @WayneWerner you're totally right.  i'm an idiot.  sorry for that.

Comment: Just remember that if you *haven't* tried something and someone suggests it (aside from, you know, `rm -rf /`), it's typically a good idea to try it ;)

Comment: What have you got against functions? While it's certainly _possible_ (and often convenient) to write a quick Python script that does everything in the global scope, it's not a recommended practice for a serious program. It's far better to encapsulate your code into functions (and classes, when appropriate). It gives you more control, it avoid polluting the global namespace with all your names, and it improves code re-usability as it allows the file to be safely imported.

Comment: @PM2Ring to answer your question, nothing.  my script calls many functions.  many of these i've written myself!  i appreciate your vigorous defense of functions, but i feel you may be drawing a bit of a hard line against the utility of scripts.  were a user new to python to read your comment, she might conclude that "it's not a recommended practice" to write scripts at all!  an infinity of functions wouldn't obviate my concern, which regards the termination of a script midway during debugging.

Comment: @dbliss Many in the Python community consider it inelegant to do *anything at all* in the global scope. Pretend it's a C program and put the body of your script in a `def main():` block at the top, then call it from an `if __name__ == "__main__":` block at the bottom. This also makes your script `import`able for unit testing (and unit-level experimentation in iPython).

Comment: @MilesErickson you are suggesting option 1 from my question. this sort of redundancy . . . inelegant, some would say.

Comment: No disagreement here. At least it's not Java.

Comment: Incidentally, Google's style guide for Python prescribes this pattern directly: https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#Main

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can* use `pdb` to plot something (at least, it works just fine for me on OS-X):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

array_x = np.arange(10)
array_y = np.arange(10)

import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

print (array_x, array_y)
```

And my console output (including a typo):

```
$ python ~/sandbox/test.py
> /Users/mgilson/sandbox/test.py(9)<module>()
-> print (array_x, array_y)
(Pdb) plt.ion()
(Pdb) plt.plit(array_x, array_y)
*** AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'plit'
(Pdb) plt.plot(array_x, array_y)
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x112120610>]
(Pdb) c
(array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]), array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]))
```

I used `plt.ion()`, but you could probably use `plt.show()` just as easily (after you've defined your plot).